# Only last element of array works

Tags: javascript, html, web, math

I am currently trying to add a function to the ingredients section of a recipe that calculates the values based on the portions (It's for a cooking site).
My problem is only the last item of the array doing this. The others aren't changing their values.

[image: Default value]

[image: When the portions are changed]

My JS looks like this:

```js
var refresh     = document.getElementById("refresh-portion");
var zutatendata = document.getElementsByClassName("zutaten-data");

for (var i = 0; i < zutatendata.length; i++)
  {
  var array = [zutatendata[i]];   console.log(zutatendata[i]);

  array.forEach(function(elem) 
    {
    var initial = elem.innerHTML;

    refresh.onclick = function() 
      {
      var input  = document.getElementById("custom-portion").value;
      var result = initial * Number(input);

      if (result.toString().length > 5)  result = result.toFixed(1);
 
      elem.innerHTML = result + " ";
      }
    })
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" >

<p id="portions">
  Für 
  <input type="text" value="1" id="custom-portion"> 
  <button id="refresh-portion">
    <i class="fas fa-sync"></i>
  </button> 
  Portionen
</p>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Möhren</div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="zutaten-data">0.33</p>kg
  </div>
  <div class="item">Kartoffeln</div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="zutaten-data">2</p>Stück
  </div>
  <div class="item">Brühe</div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="zutaten-data">1</p>l
  </div>
  <div class="item">Butter</div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="zutaten-data">5</p>kg
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It would be very nice if you could tell me why the other values aren't getting multiplied.

Comment: Because you keep replacing the `refresh.onclick` handler with a new handler *for each ingredient*, and only the last one sticks. You'll want to add *one* `refresh.onclick` handler, and when it's clicked, *then* go over all ingredients and calculate their new value.

Comment: @deceze if I get right what you mean, it will not multiply the base value in the HTML source code, which is what I want, but the value which is currently in the element. For example, if I want 2 portions at first, it will multiply by 2 and everything is fine. But if I want to change it to 3, it would multiply the 2 portions by 3.

Comment: Yes. This is generally a problem if you consider your DOM to be the source of truth. You should keep the original values in Javascript to begin with, and just write newly calculated values to the DOM each and every time. If you use systems like Angular, Vue or React, then you *start* from Javascript and build the DOM from it; not start from the DOM then read it to Javascript then influence the DOM again. This is generally a saner approach in the long run…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned up your html and added the dafault values as data attributes.

Also removed the refresh button, since the values are updated on change.

The input's minimum value is 0, so you don't get wierd values.

```js
const portion = document.querySelector("#portion");

portion.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const amounts = document.querySelectorAll(".amount")
    .forEach(amount => amount.textContent = Number(amount.dataset.default) * e.target.value);
});
```

```css
#portions {
  display: flex;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

#portions>* {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.ingredients {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.amount {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="portions">
  <span>Für</span>
  <input id="portion" type="number" value="1" min="0" />
  <p>Portionen</p>
</div>

<ul class="ingredients">
  <li class="item">
    <div class="title">Mohren</div>
    <div class="amount" data-default="0.33">0.33</div>
    <span class="unit">kg</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="title">Kartoffeln</div>
    <div class="amount" data-default="2">2</div>
    <span class="unit">Stück</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="title">Bruhe</div>
    <div class="amount" data-default="1">1</div>
    <span class="unit">l</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="title">Butter</div>
    <div class="amount" data-default="5">5 kg</div>
    <span class="unit">kg</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you are looking for something like this?

```js
 
const
 customPortion = document.querySelector('#custom-portion')
, refreshBt    = document.getElementById('refresh-portion')
, zutatendata  = document.querySelectorAll('.zutaten-data')
, portionTxt   = document.querySelector('#refresh-portion').nextSibling
, gFract = (()=>
  {              
  let fractions = [3,6,7,8,9].map(x=>({t:x,f:1/x}))
                                      // allows to establish the useful fraction  
  return (str) =>                     // ex 2.33 => {value: 2, tenths: 3}
    {                                 // where 3 is the divisor of 1
    let                               // (0.33 == 1/3) 
      value  = Number(str.trim())
    , intVal = Math.floor(value)
    , decim  = value - intVal
    , delta  = 10
    , tenths = 0
      ;
    for (let ref of fractions) 
      {
      let d = Math.abs(ref.f - decim)
      if (d < delta)
        {
        delta  = d
        tenths = ref.t
        }
      }
    if (delta < 0.01) value = intVal
    else              tenths = 0
    return ({ value, tenths })
  } }
)()
, setTenths = el =>
    {                // subtract fractions to zero 
    let 
      n = Number(el.textContent)
    , i = Math.floor(n)
    , d = n - i
      ;
    if (d===0) el.textContent = i 
    // el.textContent    = i 
    // el.dataset.tenths = d===0 ? '' : d.toFixed(2).slice(-3)
    };

// init : adding def property to each zutatendata
zutatendata.forEach( zd =>
  { 
  zd.def = gFract(zd.textContent)
  setTenths(zd)
  })
customPortion.value    = '1'
portionTxt.textContent = ' portion'

customPortion.oninput = () => // input controling for only integer value
  {
  let portions = parseInt(customPortion.value.replace(/\D/g,''), 10) || 1
  if (portions < 0) portions = 1
  customPortion.value = portions
  portionTxt.textContent =  (portions > 1) ? ' portionen' : ' portion'
  }
refreshBt.onclick = () =>
  {
  zutatendata.forEach(zd=>
    {
    let val = zd.def.value  * customPortion.valueAsNumber 
    if (zd.def.tenths > 0) val += customPortion.valueAsNumber / zd.def.tenths 
    zd.textContent = val.toFixed(2)
    setTenths(zd)
    })
  }
```

```css
:root{
  --nice_bg : #cbdbf0af;
}
* {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 20px;
  }
#portions input {
  width      : 4em;
  padding    : .1em .4em;
  text-align : right;
  box-sizing : border-box;
  direction  : rtl;
  border        : none;
  background    : var(--nice_bg);
  }
#portions button {
  cursor        : pointer;
  background    : transparent;
  color         : green;
  border        : none;
  padding       : .2em .4em;
  }
#portions button:hover {
  background    : var(--nice_bg);
  }
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 8em 8em;
}
.grid div  {
  margin-top   :  .2em;
  height       : 1.8em;
  line-height  : 1.8em;
  background   : var(--nice_bg);
  padding-left : .3em;
}
div.item > p { 
  display       : inline-block; 
  padding       : 0 .1em;
  margin        : 0;
  font-weight   : bold;
  width         : 4em;
  text-align    : right;
}
/*
.zutaten-data::after {
  content    : attr(data-tenths);
  display    : inline-block;
  width      : 1.7em;
  text-align : left;
}
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" >

<p id="portions">
  Für 
  <input type="number" value="1" id="custom-portion" min="1" step="1" > 
  <button id="refresh-portion">
    <i class="fas fa-sync"></i>
  </button> 
  Portionen
</p>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Möhren</div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="zutaten-data">0.33</p>kg
  </div>
  <div class="item">Kartoffeln</div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="zutaten-data">2</p>Stück
  </div>
  <div class="item">Brühe</div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="zutaten-data">1</p>l
  </div>
  <div class="item">Butter</div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="zutaten-data">5</p>kg
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go over the items when you click. Keep in mind that without storing the values initially somewhere in an array or an object will make this function work properly just one. Since you are reading values form html and thus for example 1st one will be 2 -> 0.66, but then if you click again it will become 0.66 * 2,   and that is not correct.

```
var refresh = document.getElementById("refresh-portion");


refresh.onclick = function () {
  var input = document.getElementById("custom-portion").value;

  var zutatendata = document.getElementsByClassName("zutaten-data");

  for (var i = 0; i < zutatendata.length; i++) {
    var array = [zutatendata[i]];

    console.log(zutatendata[i]);

    array.forEach(function (elem) {
      var initial = elem.innerHTML;
      var result = initial * Number(input);

      if (result.toString().length > 5) {
        result = result.toFixed(1);
      }

      elem.innerHTML = result + " ";
    });
  }

};
```

You can store the base values in an object and then use those values to multiply by the input value.

Comment: I have already tried that, but I want to use the same JavaScript file for multiple html pages, in which only the data is changed, which is why your idea with the base values won't work for me. And if I don't use the base values in JavaScript, it will multiply the number currently inside of the element and not the base value. Thank you for your help, though.